# How can I access Spring Model object that has list of list type data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am getting data in table with below code:

```
<tbody>
    <tr th:each="order : ${orders}">
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-link" th:text="${order?.orderId}"
                th:onclick="|showSummary('${order?.orderId}')|"></button>
        </td>
        <td th:text="${order?.customer?.emailId}"></td>
        <td width="1px !important" th:id="${'status'+order?.orderId}"><span th:text="${order?.orderStatus}"></span>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

But now I want to send all data to perform some task but I am not be able to get it using JavaScript.

Comment: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is close to the answer.

I am using below script code(at loading time) to store objects

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
       var datatotest = /*[[${orders}]]*/;
</script>
```

And then normal for each loop over 'datatotest' to get values, when an event occurs.